# A Linkedin profile link can be considered as spam?

Tags: support, spam, declined-flags

Recently I've found a StackOverflow answer that contain this phrase:
"I found the following solution" with a link to a Linkedin profile. I've commented below the answer to warn about this link, and I've flagged this answer as a spam.
My flag was declined by a moderator with this phrase:
*"a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"*

IMHO a link that direct or re-direct to a linkedin profile to a private person or company could be considered as spam. What do you think about it? I want to understand if my attitude could be wrong or not.

The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21417577/spritekit-draw-dynamic-line-between-joints/21924741#comment63286827_21924741)

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't bring this up at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

Comment: @Al E. I think my question speaking about spam and it could be not restricted only to the SO community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't exactly spam: the link probably used to be valid and point to a valid resource, but eventually the author took down the site and set it to forward to their LinkedIn profile.

Because a spam flag carries a heavy rep penalty (IIRC) declining the flag seems like the fair thing to do here.

It could be debated whether the link shouldn't be edited out. There's arguments for and against. In its current form, the link is a way of attributing the solution's original author - not terribly useful to us, but not terribly harmful, either.

Comment: I dont know: i could suppose innocent or bad attitude with all ambiguous situations (and this is not obviusly acceptable), but it would be asked to remove this link anyway.

Comment: It's ok to remove the link. But it would not be ok to hit the author with a spam flag (which I think takes away 100 reputation points and has other consequences) when they're completely innocent.

Answer (score 3):

It would be harsh to let that fall onder spam. It seems, as Pëkka mentioned, that a site went down and that it is now set up to go to the LinkedIn profile directly. The author of the answer has no interest in the link target, he doesn't earn money from it and it seems to be done in good faith on an then-existing resource that just went out now.

While this link doesn't add anything to the post any more, I would consider it a dead link (since it doesn't redirect to the intended source any more), and thus subject to removal, which I did.